# Graded Assignment [Zaption] Database

Tags: mysql, database, relationship, querying, libreoffice-base

Most specifically, I'm having trouble returning from LibreOffice Base [HSQLdb] a list of grades organized by (1) class, (2) assignment, (3) student's last name.

I want this output so I can run a script to copy the grades from the database to an online gradebook (which doesn't have an API [sadface])

I suspect several possible causes for this problem:

1. [My relational structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPIqI.png) may need tweaking.
2. I somehow need to implement a "student ID." On Zaption, Students make their submissions under whatever "ZaptionName" they choose to use.  I then manually match ZaptionName to RosterFullName in the second table shown.
3. Zaption allows multiple submissions by the same "student" for the same assignment.  Because multiple submissions are allowed, I run a FilterLowMultiples query to select the highest grade for that assignment for that student.

FilterLowMultiples:

```
SELECT MAX( "Grade" ) "Grade", "RosterFullName",
"Assignment", MAX( "ZaptionName" ) "ZapName"
FROM "SelectAssignment"
GROUP BY "RosterFullName", "Assignment"
```

SelectAssignment is below for reference:

```
SELECT "GradedAssignments"."Assignment", "Roster"."RosterFullName",
"GradedAssignments"."Grade", "ZaptionNames"."ZaptionName"
FROM "Roster", "ClassIndex", "GradedAssignments", "ZaptionNames"
WHERE "Roster"."Class" = "ClassIndex"."Class"
AND "GradedAssignments"."ZaptionName" = "ZaptionNames"."ZaptionName"
AND "ZaptionNames"."RosterFullName" = "Roster"."RosterFullName"
AND ( "GradedAssignments"."Assignment" = 'YouKnowWhatever')
```

My query to PullAssignmentGrades is as follows, but sorting by assignment fails, as there is no assignment by default unless that student submitted one, so the row is blank and that student falls to the bottom of the sort, which is bad for the transfer-to-online script I run.

```
SELECT "Roster"."RosterFirstName", "ClassIndex"."Class",
"Roster"."RosterFullName", "ClassIndex"."ClassLevel",
"FilterLowMultiples"."Grade", "FilterLowMultiples"."ZapName",
"FilterLowMultiples"."Assignment", "FilterLowMultiples"."Grade",
"FilterLowMultiples"."Assignment", "ClassIndex"."ClassDisplayOrder",
"Roster"."RosterLastName"
FROM "ClassIndex", "FilterLowMultiples", "Roster"
ORDER BY "Roster"."RosterFirstName" ASC,
"FilterLowMultiples"."Grade" DESC,
"FilterLowMultiples"."Assignment" ASC,
"ClassIndex"."ClassDisplayOrder" ASC,
"Roster"."RosterLastName" ASC
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal yet comprehensive example of desired output (esp. including sorting, and corner cases like missing assignment grades)? If the output example doesn't in itself answer why it is bad for your transfer script that students 'fall to the bottom of the sort', then that logic would be good to know as well.

Comment: Absolutely!  For a single assignment query, here is my [current output](http://i.imgur.com/szReIL7.png), copied and pasted into Calc, and here is my [desired output](http://i.imgur.com/wI0u9Il.png).  This works well enough.

Comment: The problem for me arises when I have 2 or more assignment queries, either [interwoven](http://i.imgur.com/Pit8nSb.png) so that I couldn't just script-copy the output to the web gradebook, or when non-submitters 'fall to the bottom [(actually top)](http://i.imgur.com/eL7uhdC.png)', which also interferes with script-copy, since the web gradebook rows are alphabetized.

Comment: For a multiple-assignment query, [desired output](http://i.imgur.com/GHDzIdE.png) is linked.  "2 or more assignment queries" above should read "a 2-or-more-assignment query"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `LEFT JOIN` in your query for SelectAssignment so you don't drop students who didn't do a particular assignment. Optionally you can use `COALESCE` on the potentially `NULL` values from the "GradedAssignments" table to assign a grade of 0 or I.  Like so:

```
SELECT 'YouKnowWhatever' AS "Assignment", "Roster"."RosterFullName",
  COALESCE("GradedAssignments"."Grade",0), "ZaptionNames"."ZaptionName"
FROM "Roster"
  INNER JOIN "ClassIndex" ON "Roster"."Class" = "ClassIndex"."Class"
  INNER JOIN "ZaptionNames" ON "ZaptionNames"."RosterFullName" = "Roster"."RosterFullName"
  LEFT JOIN "GradedAssignments" ON ("GradedAssignments"."ZaptionName" = "ZaptionNames"."ZaptionName" 
    AND "GradedAssignments"."Assignment" = 'YouKnowWhatever')
```

Comment: This is definitely the answer, and it's something I'd overlooked, now I just have to figure out how to implement it.